# Angular set input on change equal to a variable holding a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I know you can do something like

```
<input (input)="doSomething($event)" />
<input (input)="boolVar = $event.target.value > 5" />
```

but how can I do something like

```
funcVar = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

<input (input)="funcVar" />
```

I tried other things like

```
<input [input]="funcVar" />
<input [(input)]="funcVar" />
```

but no luck. Reason I'm doing this is that our forms are being generated from a data set, so they only way I can add on stuff like is by passing in stuff through variables that will generate the forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler should call the function. The markup would be:

```
<input (input)="funcVar($event)" />
```

for the `funcVar` member defined as:

```
public funcVar = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

If another method is assigned to `funcVar` later, that new method will be executed when the `input` event is triggered:

```
someMethodExecutedLater() {
  this.funcVar = (e) => {
    // From now on, this new function will be called by the event handler
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: So is there no way to pass in funcVar($event) through a variable? Since I can't hard code that onto the input. I need to do something like <input (input)="funcVar"> where funcVar is holding the function. Or a way to hard code it like that, but override what function funcVar is on the fly. Need it to try and evaluate what I put on the right hand side (as it will be a variable holding a function) and then call it.

Comment: Because funcVar is a variable that will change what function it's holding based on the form that's being generated

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see what you are saying (one minute)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was overthinking things. Thinking it wouldn't look up funcVar (it's late in the day) :D Thanks for the explanation!